# django "no such table" when use ModelForm.save

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a simple model and I want to save it using the ModelForm.

Here's the code:

```
#models.py
class MyArchive(models.Model):
    archive_id = models.CharField(max_length = 20, primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = True)
    archive_file = models.FileField(upload_to = "my_archives/")

#views.py
class MyArchiveForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyArchive
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyArchiveForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse('uploaded success!')
        else:
            logger.debug("invalid form")
    return HttpResponse('upload fail!')
```

I've synced DB and saw the tables created. But every time it goes to form.save then says

```
DatabaseError, no such table.
```

Is my way to save using ModelForm wrong?

UPDATE:
What's even weird that when I removed this line: `form.save()`, it fails at `if form.is_valid()` with the same error `no such table`, but when I run django in debug mode, `if form.is_valid()` works fine.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the entire database and running `syncdb` again? This command doesn't recognize changes in your models, only the new ones! If you want to push changes from your models to your database try South.

Comment: @Caumons Yeah I've tried but it still doesn't work. Actually, even I remove the `form.save()`, it fails at `if form.is_valid():`, but it works before I changed something, couldn't remember.

Comment: What fails with `form.is_valid()`?

Comment: The same error, `no such table`.

Comment: Have you checked that the table actually exists in the database?

Comment: Glad to see that you finally solved your question. Accept your own answer! :)

Comment: @Caumons, thanks for discussing with me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little trick, turns out led by bad database configuration, I was using relative path in settings.py, so it didn't find the db file at running time, but when run `django sycdb`, it can find where the db loc.

```
'default' : {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': 'sqlite.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
}
```

UPDATE:
To use relative path on db file, I should have db setting like this:

```
from os.path import dirname, join

PROJECT_DIR = dirname(__file__)

DATABASES = {
    # ...
    'NAME': join(PROJECT_DIR, 'sqlite.db'),
    # ...
}
```

see [Can I make the Django database path (for sqlite3) "cross-platform"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889388/can-i-make-the-django-database-path-for-sqlite3-cross-platform)