# Django Caching on Heroku, but Not when developing

Tags: django, caching, heroku

I want to disable caching on my Django project when developing, but have it enabled when deployed on Heroku.

Here's my current cache settings:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
        'LOCATION': os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'cache/'),
    }
}
```

I understand that that the below code will not cache on development:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
    }
}
```

My question is: How do I combine these two settings to dummy cache on my local machine, but cache on Heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set up a local settings file for your project while you're developing (just make sure you don't deploy your local settings!) - [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4909964/240418) will help.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know this was an option.  I should just add `local_settings.py` to my `.gitignore` and `except ImportError`?