# Can I use an identity hasher for testing?

Tags: python, django, testing

I have some tests for which I need to create fully-functional test users. I do this by subclassing `TestCase` in my tests, and initializing my test database in the `setUp` method. However, in order to create fully functional users, I need to give them useful passwords by calling `make_password`

This is sufficiently computationally intensive to cause my development server (a Raspberry Pi) to take multiple seconds for each test.

My question is: can I force Django to just not hash the password during tests? This would significantly improve the performance of my test suite, and give me all the benefits that come along with that.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you testing on a Raspberry Pi? Why don't you just test locally or use a VM?

Comment: Because my dev laptop is a two generation-old chromebook :P

Comment: Are you sure that the hashing consumes most of your time?

Comment: @JakubM.: The whole point of hashing functions like Bcrypt and PBKDF2 is to be as slow as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/

Basically, create a subclass of `django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher` and add your new hasher as the first entry in `PASSWORD_HASHERS` in your settings.

Comment: This is a security problem. Can I enable this only during tests?

Comment: Does `override_settings` on a test function also apply to the `setUp` method?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work. Note that you can specify an alternative settings file just when running the tests, with `python manage.py test --settings=test_settings` See my related answer on using custom settings http://stackoverflow.com/a/14545196/641955