# What is a good way in Python to allow for missing errors in the errno module?

Tags: python

I'm installing some open source software in Python that makes use of the `errno` module and want to make it installable across multiple environments whose `errno` modules might differ. What is a good pattern for this?

Here's my specific case. The code uses `errno.ETIME`. However, `ETIME` is not in every version of `errno`. For example, in Anaconda for Python 2 on Windows. (Or maybe this is specific to my Windows installation?)

Now, one way around it is to check for it and assign it if it's not there:

```
import errno
if 'ETIME' not in dir(errno):
    errno.ETIME = 127
```

But that feels hacky. Is there a best practice for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a global variable:

```
ERRNO_ETIME = 127 # Or whatever your default is.

try:
    from errno import ETIME
    ERRNO_ETIME = ETIME # If found, this will just override with correct ETIME if it was found
except ImportError:
    pass # ImportError would be thrown if it wasn't found, and you'd just keep your 127
```

You could put this in a function:

```
def get_etime():
    try:
        from errno import ETIME
        return ETIME
    except ImportError:
        return 127

ERRNO_ETIME = get_etime()
```

This is similar to how django overrides `settings.py` with `local_settings.py` for config values specific to a machine, more on that here - [Django Local Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909958/django-local-settings)

Comment: Thanks, @Bahrom. Both of those require changing existing references to errno.ETIME. I am looking for the best way that avoids changing those references.

Comment: @user3038796 not sure what you mean - you are not overriding the value of `errno.ETIME` itself - you're creating another variable. Do you want to avoid this?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to avoid creating another variable so that the existing references to it don't have to change