# I want to get current url in settings.py file in django

Tags: django, error-handling, react-google-recaptcha

I want to set an if condition in settings.py in my django app, to check the url and apply correct GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY for the site. because of difference in local host and web server domin.
I used `requests._current_scheme_host` but get an error:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 136, in check_apps_ready
raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

Comment: Can you add the logic in your settings file for defining GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY?

Comment: nope! I can not.

Comment: If you can't provide details then you will find answers hard to come by. You need to remove your current check and replace it with something

Comment: Use a Django Local Settings file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909958/django-local-settings

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone!

When working with multiple environments, create separate file for each environment and enable the required environment from the settings.py file. Ensure to add the attributes in all the env files.

For eg.  My app folder looks like this.

[image]

And now in settings.py,  will enable the required env.

[image]

In case, if you have common attributes to be used for all envs, create a common.py file under environments folder and keep it enabled in all env servers.